# Rectangle to Curve image in openCV python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to fit a rectangle image(overlay) on my another image(back). I am performing 3 operations

1. Resizing overlay image
2. Curving overlay image to fit the overlay poster placeholder
3. Rotating and Positioning overlay onto the back image placeholder and save it.

I am able to resize the image,  rotate, position and save it correctly but not able to curve it while maintaining transparency.

Please help.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

bg = cv2.imread("bg_layer.webp", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
poster = cv2.imread("7.jpeg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
poster = cv2.resize(poster,(500,700))
poster = rotate_image_with_alpha(poster, -30)

cv2.imshow("image",merge_image(bg, poster, 450, 450))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: This is my overlay image]
This is my overlay image

[image: This is my back layer]
This is my back layer

[image: Current Progress]

Comment: You need to project a rectangular image to a spesific curved contour, this is an easy task for photoshop programs but a heavy one for image processing.

Comment: it's just a textured mesh. that too is trivial for image processing, if you use the right libraries. opencv is for vision, not for replacing OpenGL

Comment: yes, left opencv and testing api with photoshop. As this is overkill for opencv and I have to create 50+ many templates like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i searched but did not found a exact solution to yor problem which is to warp a rectangular image to curved quadrilateral. So i divided your background paper and tanjiro image to 4 pieces and warped each of them rectangle-to-rectangle then brought them together. It is like approximating a curve with many lines.

These are the four pieces getting together consecutively:
[image]

This is the code block:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math


# Function to warping an image an printing it on another
def warp_and_mask(sourceP,destinationP,backIm,overlayIm):
    xi,yi = int(sourceP[0][0]),int(sourceP[0][1]) #initial points for cropping the overlay image
    xf,yf = int(sourceP[2][0]),int(sourceP[2][1])

    #Perspective transform matrix
    resmatrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.float32([[0, 0], [4724, 0], [4724, 2252], [0, 2252]]), destinationP)
    #Applying the warping to the overlay image
    masked_overlay = cv2.warpPerspective(overlayIm[yi:yf,xi:xf], resmatrix, (backIm.shape[1], backIm.shape[0]))
    #Masking the warped overlay to background image
    _,mask = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(masked_overlay,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),2,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    masked_back = cv2.bitwise_and(backIm,backIm, mask=mask)
    
    return cv2.bitwise_or(masked_back, masked_overlay)


back = cv2.imread('img/bg_layer.png')
overlay = cv2.imread('img/tanjiro.jpg')  # Replace 'your_image.png' with your image path


#Source points of the four pieces on the overlay image
srcpts1 = np.float32([[0, 0], [4724, 0], [4724, 2252], [0, 2252]])
srcpts2 = np.float32([[0, 2252], [4724, 2252], [4724, 4504], [0, 4504]])
srcpts3 = np.float32([[0, 4504], [4724, 4504], [4724, 6756], [0, 6756]])
srcpts4 = np.float32([[0, 6756], [4724, 6756], [4724, 9008], [0, 9008]])

#Destination points of the four pieces on the background layer
destpts1 = np.float32([[619, 302], [1186, 505], [1104, 692], [541, 463]])
destpts2 = np.float32([[541, 463], [1104, 692], [983, 908], [437, 651]])
destpts3 = np.float32([[437, 651], [983, 908], [835, 1102], [292, 823]])
destpts4 = np.float32([[292, 823], [835, 1102], [694, 1244], [111, 971]])


#Use the warp_and_mask function for four times on each piece
final1 = warp_and_mask(srcpts1,destpts1,back,overlay)
cv2.imshow('final', cv2.resize(final1,(0,0),fx=0.7,fy=0.7))
cv2.waitKey(0)
final2 = warp_and_mask(srcpts2,destpts2,final1,overlay)
cv2.imshow('final', cv2.resize(final2,(0,0),fx=0.7,fy=0.7))
cv2.waitKey(0)
final3 = warp_and_mask(srcpts3,destpts3,final2,overlay)
cv2.imshow('final', cv2.resize(final3,(0,0),fx=0.7,fy=0.7))
cv2.waitKey(0)
final4 = warp_and_mask(srcpts4,destpts4,final3,overlay)
cv2.imshow('final', cv2.resize(final4,(0,0),fx=0.7,fy=0.7))
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This may not be the complete answer to your question but if you increase the number of pieces approximation will be smoother and you may even work to make this whole process automated if necessary.